# Given $\Sigma$ a surface parameterized by $\Phi : D \to \Sigma$, prove a certain formula for $area(\Sigma).$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $\Sigma$ be a surface parameterized by  $\Phi : D \to \Sigma$, and let $$A=\Phi_u \cdot \Phi_u~,~B=\Phi_u \cdot \Phi_v,~ C=\Phi_v \cdot \Phi_v.$$ Prove $$area(\Sigma)=\int\int_D \sqrt{AC-B^2} dudv.$$

**What I've done:** We already know

$$area(\Sigma)=\int\int_D ||\vec{N}||dudv.$$

where $\vec{N}$ is the normal vector $~\Phi_u \times \Phi_v.$ So it suffices to show that $||\vec{N}||=\sqrt{AC-B^2}.$ Now I can do this trivially by "brute force computation", i.e., by expanding out the components of $A,B,C$ and $\vec{N},$ and showing that the expressions are equal. I was wondering though if there is a simpler way to do this, without resorting to expanding into components.

Comment: Hint : $ \| \mathrm{a}\times \mathrm{b} \| = \| \mathrm{a} \| \| \mathrm{b} \| \sin \theta $, where $\theta$ is the angle between two vectors.

Comment: Hint #2: $\sin \theta = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \theta}$.